# Dragging from Angular UI modal to div not working

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/2RBJCkxH6I6O8BIEuNLE?p=preview) I have an Angular UI modal with a text element that I need to drag and drop into a div external to the modal. I'm using the draggable and droppable functions of jQuery UI. Is this possible?

HTML

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">

    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">The Title</h4>
    </div>

    <div id="dragme" style="cursor:default">drag this text</div>

</script>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<div id="dropme">Drop here</div>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('ctl', function ($scope,$uibModal) {

      $scope.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
          templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
          backdrop: 'static',
          animation: false,
          windowClass: 'app-modal',
        }); 


      $("#dragme").draggable(); 
      $("#dropme").droppable({  
           drop: alert("dropped!") 
      }); 
});
```

Comment: I would advise you to forget jQuery when developing angularJS applications and go for some proven angularJS drag&drop solution like this: https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists

Comment: Your link points me to a "drag and drop lists" library, not draggable/droppable of a div as the question states. Also, the main problem is that the target div is not available in the Angular UI Modal.